# Oracle union with depencies on a field of a part of the union

Tags: oracle, select, union

I have a query with Union. My goal is to get the list of units (current unit UNION History unit)

I would like to add a field "IS_EQUAL_TO_CURRENT_LABEL" with the value depending of the comparison between the value of the label of the first part of the union and the same field label of the second part of the union. But I don't know how to do that.

My query:

```
-- Current units defined in currentUnits table
SELECT  currentUnits.ID AS ID, 
        SUBSTR(CD, 7) AS CODE, 
        currentUnits.CD AS LABEL, 
        1 AS IS_EQUAL_TO_CURRENT_LABEL
FROM UNIT_TAB currentUnits


UNION


--HISTORY
-- History units from histUnits
SELECT  histUnits.HIST_ID AS ID, 
        SUBSTR(CD, 7) AS CODE, 
        CD AS LABEL,      
        IF CD = (
            SELECT currentUnits.CD FROM currentUnits WHERE histUnits.HIST_ID = currentUnits.ID 
        ) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END IF
        AS IS_EQUAL_TO_CURRENT_LABEL
FROM histUnits
WHERE CD = 'MYCOMP'


-- History units from histUnits without Label
SELECT  histUnits.HIST_ID AS ID
        SUBSTR(CD, 7) AS CODE, 
        '' AS LABEL, 
        IF CD = (
            SELECT currentUnits.CD FROM currentUnits WHERE histUnits.HIST_ID = currentUnits.ID 
        ) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END IFFROM histUnits
INNER JOIN histUnitsLabels histLab on histUnits.HIST_ID = histLab.HIST_ID
WHERE HIST_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT HIST_ID FROM APPREF_HIST_LIB_ORGANES_MV
)
AND CD = 'MYCOMP'


UNION
-- ANOTHER OLD SYSTEM

SELECT  oldTableUnits.ID AS ID, 
        SUBSTR(oldTableUnits.CD, 7) AS CODE, 
        oldTableUnits.CD AS LABEL, 
        IF CD = (
            SELECT currentUnits.CD FROM currentUnits WHERE histUnits.HIST_ID = currentUnits.ID 
        ) 
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END IF
FROM OLD_UNIT_TAB oldTableUnits
```

But it's not working

My desired result:

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>   
<th>CODE</th>   
<th>LABEL</th>
<th>IS_EQUAL_TO_CURRENT_LABEL</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>A</td>
<td>A.1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>A</td>
<td>A.2</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>B</td>
<td>B.1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>61</td>
<td>A</td>
<td>DGD.A.1</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>62</td>
<td>A</td>
<td>A.2</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>63</td>
<td>B</td>
<td>DG.B.1</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in the `outer query` and use `MAX` analytical function as following:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    CODE,
    LABEL,
    CASE
        WHEN MAX(IS_EQUAL_TO_CURRENT_LABEL) OVER(
            PARTITION BY ID
            ORDER BY
                IS_EQUAL_TO_CURRENT_LABEL DESC
        ) = 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS IS_EQUAL_TO_CURRENT_LABEL FROM
(SELECT  currentUnits.ID AS ID, 
        SUBSTR(CD, 7) AS CODE, 
        currentUnits.CD AS LABEL, 
        1 AS IS_EQUAL_TO_CURRENT_LABEL
FROM UNIT_TAB currentUnits

UNION

-- History units from histUnits
SELECT  histUnits.HIST_ID AS ID, 
        SUBSTR(CD, 7) AS CODE, 
        CD AS LABEL,      
        0 AS IS_EQUAL_TO_CURRENT_LABEL
        FROM histUnits);
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks. But I update the code because I have 2 others sections in the UNION of the query. Could you please help me with that for taking in account the 4 sections (the 3 last sections should compare the label with the 1st section)?

Comment: You need same funda there also. 0 as label